# Access nested objects in API using vue resource

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm just starting out with vue resource (and ajax in general) and I'm having trouble listing an array that's nested in my API.

If this is my sample JSON:

```
{
  "item1" : "data",
  "item2" : 1234,
  "item3" : 5678,
  "item6" : "data",
  "item7" : [ {
    "id" : 0,
    "data2" : "testdata",
    "data3" : "testdata",
  },{
    "id" : 2,
    "data2" : "testdata",
    "data3" : "testdata",
  },{
    "id" : 3,
    "data2" : "testdata",
    "data3" : "testdata",
  } ]
}
```

I want to pass the item7 array through a list in my html like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="item in items">
      <li>{{ item.data2 }} {{ item.data3 }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my js:

```
window.onload = function() {

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      items: {}
    },
    ready: function () {
       this.$http.get('/api/items', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.items = data.item7[];
       });
    },

  });

};
```

Naturally this returns nothing, I'm not sure how to loop the array through `this.items = data.item7[];` with vue resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write `this.items = data.item7`, no need for `[]`.

You also need to bind `this` to the function.  When you're in the callback from the HTTP request, `this` refers to something else.  So you can use `.bind(this)` like so:

```
this.$http.get('/api/items', function(data) {
    this.items = data.item7;
 }.bind(this));
```

Lastly, you should instantiate `items` as an array if it is going to be an array:

```
data: {
  items: []
},
```